# How to use streams with interfering methods and constructors, and why not use .peek()?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'll show a simplified example of my problem to help demonstrate it.

let's say I'm trying to convert an old java code to java 8 code for style and parallelization purposes (Which i do).

this is the code:

```
    public static boolean deleteTester(List<Integer> keys) {
        DHeap dHeap = new DHeap(d, keys.size());
        DHeap_Item[] DHeap_ItemArray = keysListToDHeap_ItemArray(keys);
        dHeap.arrayToHeap(DHeap_ItemArray);

        for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
            keys.set(i, null);
            dHeap.delete(DHeap_ItemArray[i]);
            if (!someTest(keys, dHeap.getList()))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

There are several issues in the conversion:

1. I need to check every iteration, so i can't reduce/collect and then check.
2. I am accessing an array and a data structure object (which the tester is for), meaning it isn't non-interfering, and isn't  stateless operation.

Here is my attempt at replacing the for loop:

```
    return IntStream.range(0, keys.size())
            //.parallel()
            .peek(idx -> keys.set(idx, null))
            .peek(idx -> dHeap.delete(DHeap_ItemArray[idx]))
            .allMatch(e -> someTest(keys, dHeap.getList()));
```

which is much shorter and readable, however "breaks the rules" and in result unable to parallel.

So my questions are:

1. Why am I unable to use `.parallal()`? (I get a null pointer ex.)
2. Why shouldn't we use peek()? because in this code i see no other way around it.
3. What should I do when accessing outside elements?
4. How should I "transfer" the code to java 8 streams?
5. What am I missing?

I guess that the answers are intertwined.
I just started to learn java 8 so thanks a lot for all the help because I'm really stuck.

Comment: The fundamental assumption that makes parallel streams work is that all operations are non-interfering.  In fact, this is even recommended for sequential streams, in case someone new decides to come in for the first time and switch it to parallel (as I did a few months back to rather unfortunate results).

Comment: TL;DR: You have to fix these more fundamental problems before you can consider moving to the Stream interface.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I understand that the whole transferring is wrong, I'm asking how can I transfer it correctly so I won't have side effects, even If I need to change logic. because I do have to access the array and data structure and I don't see a way around it, and accessing is interfering if I understand correctly.

Comment: The Stream is irrelevant. Just ask yourself, how `someTest` is supposed to process multiple different tests in parallel, when the arguments to these concurrent invocations point to the *same* data structure. This can’t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q**: Why am I unable to use .parallal()?
>
> **Q**: What should I do when accessing outside elements?

you can use it in a parallel stream, there is no problem when the action doesn't modify shared state there, for example:

```
stream.peek(System.out::println).allMatch(...);
```

If the action modifies shared state, it is responsible for providing the required synchronization, for example:

```
stream.peek(it->{synchronized(lock){ keys.set(idx, null); }}).allMatch(...);
```

> **Q**: Why shouldn't we use peek()?

you can using the `peek()` method, but you should avoiding using `peek()` if you can't control the stream, for example:

```
boolean foo(){ stream.peek(...).allMatch(..); }

//a violate rule
Stream<?> foo(){
  /*you need avoiding using peek() here since you can't control the stream*/
}
```

> **Q**: How should I "transfer" the code to java 8 streams?

there is a detailed description how to operates a stream in its package summary [java.util.stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, so if I add the synchronized to peek() can I still run it sequently?

Comment: And am I misunderstanding the non-interfering definition?

Comment: also should I add the .peek() methods to the .allMatch() instead.

Comment: @AdamShem-Ur yes, you can. [non-interfering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference) is another aspect of the stream, you can see the demo carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely should not use `peek` like this.  Streams API documentation does not specify that elements will pass through `peek` only until the test in `allMatch` fails.  All bets are off the the stream is parallel as `anyMatch` is not required to be evaluated in order and one thread is allowed to keep executing `peek` even after another thread has encountered a condition that violates `anyMatch`.

Even if the stream is sequential, `peek` can execute an unexpected number of times in certain cases.  Consider the following code:

```
List<List<Integer>> data = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList(1,2), 
    Arrays.asList(3,4,5), 
    Arrays.asList(6,7));

data.stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .allMatch(x -> x < 4);
```

You might think that it will print numbers up to 3, but in fact it will print numbers up to 5.

Comment: that's a good example, but currently this is bug, not related to peek. It's how `flatmap` acts...

Comment: Oh, so should I move the code Inside peek to allMatch?